# php array and insert

Tags: php, mysql

help pls.
I want to insert database Urunler[]. but it does not get it working.

```
<select name="urunler[1]"> <option selected="" value="DF-12">DF-12</option></select>
<select name="urunler[2]"> <option selected="" value="DF-5">DF-5</option></select>
<select name="urunler[3]"> <option selected="" value="DF-15">DF-15</option></select>

$urunler = array();
$values = array();


foreach($_POST[$urunler] as $key => $urun_value) { 
    $values[] = "('" . mysql_real_escape_string($urun_value) . "')";
}

$val_string = implode(',', $values);

$ekle = mysql_query (
    "INSERT INTO siparis_onay (
    id,urunkodu,urunfiyat,uadet,ekurun)
    VALUES ('$id','$urunkodu','$urunfiyat','$uadet','$val_string')
    ");
```

Comment: And what error are you getting or what unexpected behavior are you seeing?

Comment: I see no value in databese

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="urunler[]">
    <option value="DF-5">DF-5</option>
    <option value="DF-12">DF-12</option>
    <option value="DF-1">DF-1</option>
</select>

<?php 


foreach ($_POST['urunler'] as $key => $value) {
    $values[] = "('" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "')";
}

$val_string = implode(',', $values);
```